# nodejs - function scope with await

Tags: node.js, function, scope

This is the layout of my file:

```
router.post('/data/*', async function (req, res, next) {
  var status1 = 0, status2 = 0, status3 = 0;
  await function1(req, (err,res) => {
    if (err) {
        status1 = 400
    } else {
        status1 = 200
    }
  })
  await function2(req, (err,res) => {
    if (err) {
        status2 = 400
    } else {
        status2 = 200
    }
  })
  await function3(req, (err,res) => {
    if (err) {
        status3 = 400
    } else {
        status3 = 200
    }
  })
  //
  // Here, all status variables are zero - why?
  //
  if (status1 > 200 || status2 > 200 || status3 > 200) {
    res.status(400)
    res.send({'resp':'Error'})
  } else {
    res.status(200)
    res.send({'resp':'Success'})
  }

}
```

I have three functions invoked with `await` to process the `POST` payload. Each of the function may or may not complete successfully. For now, I am going with the option where, if any function is an error, then I consider the status as `400` and send response accordingly. If not, then I consider the status as `200` and send response as success.

My question is, when I am checking status code, it never carries the value set in functions. Isn't `await` expected to make the functions execute serially?

Comment: You have to return a Promise from your functions and set the  responses on a variable. e.g `const status1 = await function1(/*return Promise from function*/)`

Comment: I have tried `return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {resolve(s)})` where `s` is a status value. But, at the `if` statement, the `status1` is undefined.

Comment: Please, provide function1, etc. It's unclear how they work. Usually you don't need to use callbacks together with promises. It's either one or another.

Comment: I can't; those aren't my functions.

Comment: But they must be defined somewhere..?

Comment: Per payload, They insert multiple rows into a database. The call back returns a status of each insert which is logged. Those functions are sync and they do inset with an await. Db is postgresql.